# Java - Get class object for array of type A from class object for type A?

Tags: java, generics

If I have `Class<A> cls`, is there any way to transform that into `Class<A[]> arrCls`?

Comment: what are you trying to do that leads you to ask this question? To prevent us from playing the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it depends on what you need.

If you simply need the Class object for the array type, then approach should work:

```
  Class<A> cls = ...;
  Object array = Array.newInstance(cls, 1);
  Class<?> arrCls = array.getClass();
```

That should work if `A` is a concrete class or a type parameter.

However, if you need `arrCls` to be declared with the type `Class<A[]>` ... then I don't know of a way to do it, without resorting to "unsafe" type casts.  The `newInstance(...)` method returns an `Object`, so you've erased the generic typing.

Comment: "Array.newInstance(cls, 1)" or even 0

Comment: "(I understand that the root issue is that generic type inference in Java cannot make the connection between <A> and <A[]>.)" That's not it at all. A method can easily return `Class<T[]>` if it wants to. `Array.newInstance()` doesn't return `Class<T[]>` *precisely because that is not necessarily true* -- if `cls` was `int.class`, `A` would be `Integer`, but `arrCls` would be the class of `int[]`, not `Integer[]`.

Comment: OK ... so I don't understand that.  But `Integer.TYPE != Integer.class`, even though they have the same type (`Class<Integer>`).  I guess it must be that `Class<int>` is illegal because type parameters can't be primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to instantiate a variable with a type of `Class<A[]>` from `Class<A>`, then you could use this method:

```
public static <T> Class<T[]> classToArrayClass(Class<T> type) {
    return (Class<T[]>) Array.newInstance(type, 0).getClass();
}
```

For example:

```
Class<String> cls = String.class;
Class<String[]> clsArray = classToArrayClass(cls);
System.out.println(clsArray.isArray());
System.out.println(clsArray.getComponentType().getName());

/* Output:
true
java.lang.String
*/
```

Comment: You've left of that you are ignoring or suppressing an unsafe typecast warning.